# Python3 instruction assert with condition

Tags: python, if-statement, assert

I work in python 3.  I calculate the average and I would like to use an assert instruction.

```
moyenne = somme/nombre_notes   if somme==50 and nombre_notes==4 :   assert moyenne==12.5 ,"Erreur de calcul"
```

This solution is operational but how write my assert in 1 line and begin by assert ....?
Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can build the conditional checks into the assertion like this:

```
somme=50
nombre_notes=4
moyenne = somme/nombre_notes
assert somme == 50 and nombre_notes == 4 and moyenne == 12.5, "Erreur de calcul"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a solution:
Do a unit test as shown here:

```
assert division(50, 4) == 12.5, "erreur de calcul"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).